# BizTalk C# namespace collision in orchestrations

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

In an orchestration I'm trying to set properties in an outgoing EDI message.
In the message assignment I wrote:

```
msgEDI850(EDI.DestinationPartyName) = HelperObj.EDIParty;
```

At compile time it chokes saying DestinationPartyName is not defined.

The error details show it's looking in the wrong namespace. The C# compiler is looking in "MyCompany.EDI" instead of "EDI" as it should be.

The IDE code completion shows EDI.DestinationPartyName is valid.

I changed the application namespace to not include EDI at any level.
This does not work:

```
msgEDI850(global::EDI.DestinationPartyName) = HelperObj.EDIParty;
```

Any suggestions on how to get it to use the correct namespace in the auto generated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a long standing and expected behavior.  Simply, the XLang compiler is easily confused by clashing namespaces, no matter where they are in the hierarchy.

Sorry, but the solution is that you cannot use any BizTalk owned namespace in any of your apps.  *There is no way around this.*  USING is not supported either.

So, no EDI, BTS, BTS2, BizTalk etc.

Comment: Stackoverflow and you to the rescue. Thanks

Comment: A reference to an assembly that has unused items with EDI in the namespace breaks it.